# How to write a YACC token catchall rule

Tags: token, yacc, rules

As learning curve exercise, I am using lex and yacc to convert ‘C’ header files into something that my Prolog compiler can use to call dll’s and extract objs from lib files. The compiler needs method name and parameters to pass. For example

```
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glAccum (GLenum op, GLfloat value);
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glAlphaFunc (GLenum func, GLclampf ref);
WINGDIAPI GLboolean APIENTRY glAreTexturesResident (GLsizei n, const GLuint *textures, GLboolean *residences);
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glArrayElement (GLint i);
```

Should be transformed to

```
glAccum (unsigned op, core::real32 value);
glAlphaFunc (unsigned func, core::real32 ref);
glAreTexturesResident (integer n, pointer textures, pointer residences) -> core::char8;
glArrayElement (integer i);
```

using some typedefs at the beginning of the header file

```
typedef unsigned int GLenum;
typedef unsigned char GLboolean;
typedef unsigned int GLbitfield;
typedef signed char GLbyte;
typedef short GLshort;
typedef int GLint;
typedef int GLsizei;
typedef unsigned char GLubyte;
typedef unsigned short GLushort;
typedef unsigned int GLuint;
typedef float GLfloat;
typedef float GLclampf;
typedef double GLdouble;
typedef double GLclampd;
typedef void GLvoid;
```

There is an extra table to transform the 'C' built in types to Prolog built in types.

I have got a working lexer for all the tokens I currently need.
**My question is**. While writing the rules in the yacc portion of my project. How do I write a global rule to catch all of the TOKENS that I have not written rules for yet, so that I can progressively work on my project. Writing and testing each rule. The first thing that I want to work on, is to trap the typedef’s and write their associations away to a small lookup table so that later when I process the function and parameter lists I can insert the correct PROLOG primitives. Please note. I am not asking how to write a rule to trap the typedefs. This I have a rough idea how to do. I am asking how to have a global catch all for all the other TOKENs that my ‘lexer’ is returning to the ‘yaccer’, while I am developing my project. In the ‘lexer’ you normally have an empty function call to do nothing with the text that is being read, like.

```
“LATER”         |
“JUNK”          |
{WS}+           |
\n              |
.               ;
```

What is the YACC equivalent.

Comment: Yacc will generate a "syntax error" for any token sequences your parser does not handle yet.

Comment: Correct. See my comments to jaeheung's answer of the Aug 21 at 5:04.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as yyparse() encounters input that does not match any known grammar, it calls the yyerror() function.
Refer to "Error handling" section of Yacc manual.

Comment: Correct. But how does one develop a 'YACCer'. Take a medium complex language like 'C'. Very few people can sit down and write all the YACC rules to parse 'C' straight away. I think that one has to write some type of global rule to catch everything. Then one starts writing individual rules one by one, testing and refining. Moving tokens from the global rule to individual rules until all tokens are correctly consumed and your parsing is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want error recovery.
This is part of my implementation for error recovery:

```
line:   stmt eol
        { $$ = $1;}
        | T_NEWLINE
        { $$ = NULL;}
        | error T_NEWLINE
        {
                $$ = NULL;
                yyerrok;
        }
```

When there is an syntax error, the third rule makes the parser skip to the next line of input and keep parsing.
yyerror() is still called. Not sure exactly when it is called, but my guess is before invoking the error rule.
You still need to read the "error recovery" section of the manual.

Comment: Not exactly. Again as an example lets pretend that I am writing a 'C' parser. I have got my lex part sorted out. Now I want to write the yacc part. There are many rules that I now have to write to put together all of the things that 'C' can be. If I want first write the rule for the switch statement. How do I write a temporary catch all rule or rules to deal with all of the other stuff that might be in a 'C' source file while I refine the switch yacc rules. In other words how to develop a yaccer. All examples in books show the yacc rules complete.

Comment: When you have a subset of a language implemented, the rest to be implemented is actually invalid syntax for the time being. That's why it needs to be handled by an error handling routine. Lex's job is to convert character stream into token stream, and it makes sense to have the catch all rule to pass the character as is. But Yacc's job is doing something meaningful for a given syntax. When a syntax is not defined, there cannot be a meaningful action for Yacc. Let me ask this way: What do you want to do if "catch all" rule was possible?

Comment: I want to catch everything else that I am not working on right now. So if I have 5 rules to write. I work on rule one until that rule is working. Then I work on rule two etc. While I am working through the rules I don't want yyerror to be triggering on all the tokens that I have not written rules for. The yyerror should trigger when what ever rule I am currently developing is not working Again. I want to know how to go from zero rules written with a catch all to all rules written and no catch all because all my rules writing is processing all tokens. Thanks for your patience with my question.

Answer (score 0):

A way to print the tokens which do not match any rule in yacc  and  continue the parsing is may be by adding this rule in your yacc file:

```
| error  {
    char *text;
    $<symbol_table>$->cb = malloc(sizeof(struct code_block));
    text = strdup(yytext);
    $<symbol_table>$->cb->function_call= text;
    $<symbol_table>$->cb->pos =yylineno;
    *yytext=NULL;
    printf("error: %s at line no %d\n",$<symbol_table>$->cb->function_call,$<symbol_table>$->cb->pos);**
         }
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks very interesting